# Azure Search and using ends with in Array

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am using the latest `Microsoft.Azure.Search` SDK with the following search parameters. I have filter ID's that are MFR-1, MFR-2, MFR-3, etc.  I am trying to bring back ANY record that has Filter ID that starts with MFR.

It seems that this should be simple query, but I am not finding a way to make this work with the SDK.

```
var Params = new SearchParameters()
{
    SearchMode = SearchMode.Any,
    QueryType = QueryType.Full,
    Top = 72,
    Skip = 0,
    IncludeTotalResultCount = true,
    Filter = "FilterIDs/any(c: c eq 'MFR-57')",
    OrderBy = new List<string> { "Sort", "Title"},
    Facets = new List<string>() { "Filters,count:500,sort:value" }
};
```

Data looks like this:

```
{
"id": "691",
"RecordType": "product",
"FilterIDs": [
    "MFR-106",
    "36-250",
    "36-265"
],
}
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't appear to work with arrays as the title would suggest.

[Contains / in array in Azure Search (Preview)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153803/contains-in-array-in-azure-search-preview)

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding , you are looking for a filter express that could filter all record whose `FilterIDs` string collection(array) contains item value started with "MFR" .

As [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-troubleshoot-collection-filters#rules-for-filtering-string-collections%20are%20eq%20and%20ne.) indicated :

> Inside lambda expressions for string collections, the only comparison
>   operators that can be used are eq and ne.

So I am afraid there is no way to do fuzzy search here.

But if your filter ids are enumerable , maybe you can use the filter express as below :

```
FilterIDs/any(c: c eq 'MFR-1') or FilterIDs/any(c: c eq 'MFR-2') or FilterIDs/any(c: c eq 'MFR-3') or ....
```

I think it would be a work around here, it works for me on my side . 
Hope it helps.

Comment: I would use this to shorten the code: `FilterIDs/any(c: search.in(c, 'MFR-57, MFR-94'))` although it would maybe make more sense to combine the fields into one string and then do a "like" type query.  Thanks for the answer... I'll keep searching for a solution.  We have 1000's of manufacturers.